# mochajs & chaijs - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, web, mocha.js, chai

I am creating an bill tracking application that is having users create bills based on criteria I have created using javascript.

I am tasked with performing acceptance testing.

This is my code so far:
My index.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bill');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

var billSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
  type: { type: String, required: true },
  dueDate: { type: Date, required: true },
  company: { type: String, required: true },
  amtDue: { type: Number, required: true },
  paidStatus: { type: String, required: true }
});

var bill = mongoose.model('bill', billSchema);

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() 
{
  app.get('/', (req, res) => 
  {
    bill.find({}, function(err, bills) 
    {
      if (err) 
      {
        console.log(err)
        res.render('error', {})
      } 
      else 
      {
        res.render('index', { bills: bills })
      }
    });
  });

  app.get('/bills/new', (req, res) => 
  {
    res.render('bill-form', { title: "New bill", bill: {} })
  });

app.get('/bills/:id/update', (req, res) => 
{
    let id = ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id)

    bill.findById(id, function(err, bill) 
    {
      if (err) 
      {
        console.log(err)
        res.render('error', {})
      } 
      else 
      {
        if (bill === null) {
          res.render('error', { message: "Not found" })
        } else {
          res.render('bill-form', { title: "Update bill", bill: bill })
        }
      }
    });
});

app.post('/bills/new', function(req, res, next) {
    let newbill = new bill(req.body);
    newbill.save(function(err, savedbill)
    {
      if (err) 
      {
        console.log(err)
        res.render('bill-form', { bill: newbill, error: err })
      } 
      else 
      {
        res.redirect('/bills/' + savedbill.id);
      }
    });
});
app.get('/bills/:id', (req, res) => 
{
    let id = ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id)

    bill.findById(id, function(err, bill) 
    {
      if (err)
      {
        console.log(err)
        res.render('error', {})
      } 
      else 
      {
        if (bill === null) 
        {
          res.render('error', { message: "Not found" })
        } 
        else 
        {
          res.render('bill-detail', { bill: bill})
        }
      }
    });
});

app.post('/bills/:id/update', (req, res, next) => 
{
    let id = ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id)
    bill.updateOne({"_id": id}, { $set: req.body }, function(err, details)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err)
            res.render('error', {})
        }
        else
        {
            res.redirect('/bills/' + id)
        }
    });
});

app.post('/bills/:id/delete', (req, res) => 
{
    let id = ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id)
    bill.deleteOne({_id: id}, function(err, product)
    {
        res.redirect("/")
    });
});

app.post('/api/bills', (req, res) => 
{
    let newbill = new bill(req.body)

    newbill.save(function (err, savedbill) 
    {
        if (err) 
        {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).send("There was an internal error")
        }
        else 
        {
            res.send(savedbill)
        }
    });
});

app.post('/api/bills', (req, res) => 
{
    bill.find({}, function(err, bills)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).send("Internal server error")
        }
        else
        {
            res.send(bills)
        }
    });
});

app.get('/api/bills', (req, res) => 
{
    bill.find({}, function(err, bills)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).send("Internal server error")
        }
        else
        {
            res.send(bills)
        }
    });
});

app.get('/api/bills/:id', (req, res) => 
{
    let id = ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id)

    bill.findById(id, function(err, bill) 
    {
        if (err) 
        {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).send("Internal server error")
        }
        else
        {
            if (bill === null) 
            {
                res.status(404).send("Not found")
            } 
            else 
            {
                res.send(bill)
            }
        }
    });
  });

app.put('/api/bills/:id', (req, res) => 
{
    let id = ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id)

    bill.updateOne({"_id": id}, { $set: req.body }, function(err, details) 
    {
        if (err) 
        {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).send("Internal server error")
        } 
        else 
        {
            res.status(204).send()
        }
    });
  });

app.delete('/api/bills/:id', (req, res) => 
{
    let id = ObjectID.createFromHexString(req.params.id)

    Review.deleteOne({"_id": id}, function(err) 
    {
      if (err) 
      {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).send("Internal server error")
      } 
      else 
      {
        res.status(204).send()
      }
    });
  });
});



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
module.exports.app = app;
module.exports.schema = bill;
```

Then I have a javscript dedicated to testing

```
let assert = require('assert');
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let serverAndSchema = require('../index');
let server = serverAndSchema.app
let Bill = serverAndSchema.schema
let should = chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Bills', function() {
  describe('/GET bill', function() {

    it('should get the specified bill', function(done) {
      let expectedBill = new Bill({
        type: "Test Type",
        dueDate: "12/3/2018T06:00:00.000Z",
        company: "Test Company",
        amtDue: "100",
        paidStatus: "Test Status"
      });

      expectedBill.save(function(err, savedBill) {
        chai.request(server)
          .get('/api/bills/'+savedBill.id)
          .end((err, res) => {
            res.should.have.status(200);
            res.body.should.be.a('object');
            res.body.should.have.property('type').eql(savedBill.type)
            res.body.should.have.property('dueDate').eql(savedBill.dueDate)
            res.body.should.have.property('company').eql(savedBill.company)
            res.body.should.have.property('amtDue').eql(savedBill.amtDue)
            res.body.should.have.property('paidStatus').eql(savedBill.paidStatus)
            res.body.should.have.property('_id').eql(savedBill.id)
            done();
          })
        });
      });
   });
});
```

The data is added to my database, but I get this error when I try to run the test:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
  at 
C:\Users\Martae\Documents\Github\BillTracker\test\bill.js:29:46
```

Any help with this is appreciated!

Comment: In the `expectedBill.save` callback, can you `console.log(savedBill)`?

Comment: I cant. When I type npm test it shows me the typeError above.

Comment: The error is caused by `chai.request(server).get('/api/bills/'+savedBill.id)` so just log it before.

Comment: It didnt work :( still shows the typeError

Comment: Try this? https://pastebin.com/Ma1JqmkA

Comment: you can also try replacing the two `savedBill.id` in your code with `savedBill._id`

Comment: The replacing did not work and the pastelink worked, but when I try putting the chai request in, it gives me the error. I updated the post with the index.js file this is attached to. I dont know if that helps see what the problem is.

Comment: So when you tried the pastebin, *what was the output*?

Comment: (node:1528) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Example app listening on port 3000!
  Bills
    /GET bill
undefined

Comment: it worked, but there was nothing that was being outputted to be tested

Comment: It didn't output "nothing", it output `undefined`. Which is the value of `savedBill` and the reason for the error. Which means the saving fails. Your chai test doesn't check if the new Bill is actually saved, which is the one thing that fails.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked the Bill schema, I found that the issue is caused by your `due date` format. So, the mongo saved is failed and you got `undefined` for `savedBill` and when you try to access `id`, it throws the error that you got.

Here is the solution:

```
      let expectedBill = new Bill({
        type: "Test Type",
        dueDate: "2018-03-13T06:00:00.000Z", // change date to standardized format
        company: "Test Company",
        amtDue: "100",
        paidStatus: "Test Status"
      });      

      expectedBill.save(function(err, savedBill) {
        const id = savedBill._id; // store id, it is always returned as _id

        chai.request(server)
          .get('/api/bills/'+id)
          .end((err, res) => {
            // ...
            done();
          });
      });
```